# Craft 3 protecting a page with a password?

Tags: craft3, plugins, users

I have used the Guest Entries to create a plugin where anonymous users can create a entry. I have a password field on each entry. Now I want the guests who have created the entry to be able to login with this password and edit the entry they created. I don't need user validation etc for this, just a single password. Is this possible in Craft 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is possible, just follow this guide: https://noahread.net/blog/create-password-protected-pages-in-craft

After submission you get back an `entry` variable containing every information about the recently posted entry (the variable name can be changed in Guest Entries settings), so you can display the user her/his password after submission.

I use a little different approach:

I generate the password JS into a hidden field on the entry submission form, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="fields[quote_password]" id="quote_nonce" value="">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var qp = Math.random().toString(36).substring(10),
        nonce_holder = document.querySelector('#quote_nonce');
    nonce_holder.setAttribute("value", qp);
</script>
```

Then on entry page I check if the user has set a correct password OR the user has a cookie with the password (if the user posts a correct password it is stored on the device for 2 days in a cookie) OR the user is an admin:

```
{% if currentUser %}
    {% set isAdmin = currentUser.IsInGroup('admin') %}
{% else %}
    {% set isAdmin = false %}
{% endif %}

{% if craft.app.request.getParam('password') == entry.quote_password or getSecureCookie( 'quote_password' ) == entry.quote_password or isAdmin %}

    {% if craft.app.request.getParam('password') == entry.quote_password %}
        {% if entry.expiryDate.timestamp is defined %}
            {% set expiryDate = entry.expiryDate.timestamp %}
        {% else %}
            {% set expiryDate = now | date_modify("+2 days").timestamp %}
        {% endif %}

        {% do craft.cookies.setSecure('quote_password', craft.app.request.getParam('password'), expiryDate ) %}
    {% endif %}

    ... Entry content ...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with Craft out the box, and would require a module / plugin to add this functionality.

Firstly to write the password to the database and encrypt it, so it's not stored in plain text.

Then it would just be a case of having a controller (https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/coding-guidelines.html#controllers) that checks this password from a form submission and unlocks the ability to edit the entry again.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not exactly what's being asked for by @Billy, but for those who came here googling something like "password protection Craft CMS 3" and who do want to use Craft's user authentication system, I recommend using the [`{% requireLogin %}` tag](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/tags/requirelogin.html) in your Twig templates.